Is the average distance from the average statistically meaningful?
Where this value is defined as $$\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\overline{x} - x_i|$$ does it have any significance or use in statistics?

Have a look at mean deviation https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html

Also called the mean absolute deviation about the mean, and less than or equal to the standard deviation.  Note that the mean absolute deviation about the median is typically smaller or the same than about the mean

do any of the responses below answer your question?

yes, this concept is fundamental significance in inteǵral calculus, given that the upper side and lower side from average are equal in all integrals.
This means that when your statistics class is using integration, it implicitly has this property of the distange from average included in the calculation.

In a dataset of $n$ observations where $\bar x$ is the mean of the variable $x$,
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\overline{x} - x_i|$$
is known as mean absolute deviation (MAD). It characterizes the spread or dispersion of the data about the mean in a manner similar to variance or standard deviation. Smaller MAD indicates less variability about the mean while a larger MAD indicates greater variability about the mean.
While variance and standard deviation have useful properties for optimization problems and computing derivatives and integrals, they are sensitive to outliers because they sum the squared deviations about the mean. This squaring of the deviations gives disproportionate weight to deviations that are unusually large. In contrast, MAD sums the absolute value of the deviations about the mean. This makes MAD a more robust measure of dispersion in datasets containing outliers. In other words, if a dataset contains some extreme outliers, then MAD will give a more accurate picture of how the data are distibuted about the mean as opposed to the variance or standard deviation.
